# how to build a method inside setState() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, state

I built this code for a React app. I want, once I click on the 'AGGIUNGI JACK' button, that the state keeps adding automatically that number every set interval. The problem is when I click on the button, I get this message

'setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.'

Is there a way to nest the set interval method inside the set state?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Square from "./components/square";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      jack: 777
    };

    this.tantajack = this.tantaJack.bind(this);
  }

  tantaJack = () => {
    this.setState(
      setInterval({ jack: (this.state.jack += 4323423) }, 100)
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Square />
        <p onClick={this.mangiaJack}>{this.state.jack}</p>
        <button onClick={this.tantaJack}>AGGIUNGI JACK</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Don't use this.state when setting tho.setState. it's asynchronous and might not reflect the value of state you expect.

Comment: should I use a dummy argument to pass in the function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the ordering and do a `setInterval` that takes a function that calls `setState` instead:

```
tantaJack = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      return { jack: previousState.jack + 4323423 };
    });
  }, 100);
};
```

Comment: thanks, why did you pass the argument previousState though?

Comment: @Enrico When you update state that is derived from something that is already in your state, you should give `setState` a function and return the state updates from that. React will pass the previous state to this function as first argument, so you don't get race conditions. [You can read more about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: thanks a lot. so all the tutorials I am watching that use setState({this.state.apple: apple + 3}) are basically wrong or deprecated :(?

Comment: @Enrico It will not always introduce errors, but it is good practice to use the function version of `setState` if the update depends on something that already is in state. [This simple example shows what might go wrong](https://codesandbox.io/s/0opov1676p).